# Glimpse not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, glimpse

Watched the Scott H. videos on [their site](http://getglimpse.com/). Followed the same procedures.  But I only see a change in my web config and a new .dll

Does anyone know if other files are supposed to come in with the project.

When I navigate to localhost:####/Glimpse/Config or Config/ I get 404.

Comment: You'll get more attention if you use the right tags.  I assume this is `asp.net`?

Comment: Did you dl it through nuget and install it in your project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glimpse now supports Asp.net webforms!

Activate it at  `localhost:####/glimpse.axd`

Answer (score 0):

make sure your site application pool is running with .NET 4.0 not 2.0, in my case that solved the issue